# Test if an object is an empty object in a AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I have a simple object in a controller which can sometimes be empty (`{}`).

```
app.controller('TestController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.testObject = {};
});
```

I want to hide or show some DOM-elements in the corresponding template when the object is empty or not.

I tried to do it with a simple `<div ng-if="vm.testObject">` but when `vm.testObject === {}` it is considered `true` in the `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-if="vm.testObject">
    Test Object is not empty
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!vm.testObject">
    Test Object is empty
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to check for an empty object in the template? Preferably without adding new variables to the scope.

Here is a working Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qed2MKmuedcktGGqUNi0?p=preview

Comment: How about a function, eg `vm.isEmpty = function(obj) { return Object.keys(obj).length === 0; }`. Then you can use `ng-if="vm.isEmpty(vm.testObject)"`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you ok with moving the equality check to the `ng-if`?

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-if="!equals({}, vm.testObject)">
    Test Object is not empty
  </div>
  <div ng-if="equals({}, vm.testObject)">
    Test Object is empty
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, provide a helper on the scope

```
app.controller('TestController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.testObject = {};

  vm.empty = function() {
      return vm.testObject === {};
  };
});
```

then

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-if="!vm.empty()">
    Test Object is not empty
  </div>
  <div ng-if="vm.empty()">
    Test Object is empty
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this helper even work? In Javascript `{} === {}` gives false.

Comment: vm.empty = function(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).length === 0;
};

Answer (score 43):

You should use an AngularJs filter:

Javascript:

```
app.filter('isEmpty', [function() {
  return function(object) {
    return angular.equals({}, object);
  }
}])
```

Html template:

```
<div ng-if="!(vm.testObject | isEmpty)">
  Test Object is not empty
</div>
<div ng-if="vm.testObject | isEmpty">
  Test Object is empty
</div>
```

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J6H8VzUKnsNv1vSsRLfB?p=preview

Comment: You're right, thanks for helping me out there! Just corrected the answer.

Comment: For isNotEmpty `return !angular.equals({}, object);`

Comment: like this solution based on angular's framework instruments, i guess it is in a "canonical way" to archieve this goal

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I find easier to check if the Object has keys.

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <div ng-if="Object.keys(vm.testObject).length">
    Test Object is not empty
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!Object.keys(vm.testObject).length">
    Test Object is empty
  </div>
</div>
```

It's simple and readable.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me.  Upvoted by mistake.

Comment: it doens't works for me. Using version 1.3.1  (yeah, i know that is older..)

Answer (score 0):

This will work. check the Length

```
<div ng-if="!!vm.testObject && vm.testObject.length > 0">
  Test Object is not empty
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to a JSON string using the built-in AngularJS `json` filter and do a comparison like this:

```
<div ng-if="vm.testObject | json) != '{}'">
    Test Object is not empty
</div>
```